# Traducir "oro en paño"

Tags: traducción

¿Cómo se traduciría la frase "guardar como oro en paño" a inglés? No quiero una traducción literal sino una expresión que captura las sensaciones de la frase original. Los hilos de [WordReference](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=1069593) dan algunas sugerencias pero no me parecen satisfactorias. Para un poco más de contexto, doy el siguiente ejemplo:

> Guardaba la carta como oro en paño.

Comment: Traduciones a inglés son siempre off-topic aquí. Esto es un sitio sobre Español.

Answer (score 2):

en ingles, puede usa la frase "he saved the letter like it was made out of gold"

It is a relatively common saying in english as well. It means that the object is valued highly by the person.

Answer (score 0):

La referencia de "guardar como oro en paño" es sobre una lámina de oro para decorar esculturas  y demás obras de arte. Al ser tan delgadas como hojas de papel. Es muy fácil que se rompan, por lo que se transportaban envueltas en una especie de papel (actualmente se utiliza papel de seda) que al ser poco poroso, si se quedaba algun residuo de esas láminas podrían recuperarlo fácilmente. Y normalmente se agrupan en "libritos" para que tengan mayor peso y sean más resistentes para transportarlas.

Por lo que la frase no se refiere al valor monetario de las cosas (en este caso de la carta) directamente. Si no, a lo frágil que puede ser, aunado al valor sentimental que puede tener.

Así que animándome a hacer alguna "traducción" podría ser algo así:

> She kept the letter as if it were made of the most fragile glass.

Comment: Es ésta la civilización que hemos alcanzado en Europa y que hemos de conservar como paño en oro.

That is precisely the civilisation
which we have achieved here in Europe and that is the civilisation which we must hold on to.